# Script Task throwing error when reading 700MB flat text file

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to read a 700 MB flat text file. I'm using a script task for it. The data is getting stored in a DataTable. When I'm running the package in my local machine, its running fine.

But when I deploy the package to SSISDB, it runs for some time and then the script task fails showing error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

The machine which has SSISDB installed has 2GB of RAM available out of 8GB. When the process starts, it goes down to 1GB and then the process fails.

My question is, is it happening due to less RAM available or is there some other problem?

Comment: That error usually indicates that you have a dll you reference in your script task but is not installed in the GAC on the server.  It also can mean that you are referencing a variable that is not defined but that would error on the workstation as well.  I have also had that error due to microsoft office trying to run in 64-bit, it might be set to run as 32 bit on the workstation but not on the server.

Comment: Hi Joe, There is another script task also, which is reading 40KB file, and that's running fine. So, I don't think its a dll reference issue. I've changed to 32bit on the server in configuration, so that doesn't look like an issue. There are other packages which are running fine for the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it was a problem due to less RAM available. Now, I'm matching the data present in the file with a table and only inserting data which matches, which is around some thousand rows compared to approx 2 million rows before.

The process is running fine now and I've not made any other changes. Also in another forum, it got confirmed. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/70e3d1ea-b1d8-49cf-8fdc-48e5bc7e92e7/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-while-reading-700mb-flat-text-file?forum=sqlintegrationservices#53455774-23af-4bc6-92ef-5700188b93a5